# Python thread release

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-multithreading

I running 2 thread in python and execute the function `Do()`.

```
import sys, threading

def do():
    print ("Execute")

def run():
    def start_thread():
        thread = threading.Thread(target = do)
        thread.start()
        thread.join()
        return thread

    t1 = start_thread()
    t2 = start_thread()

run()
print('Press enter to Quit')
sys.stdin.readline()
```

After running the `run()` function, the threads `t1` and `t2` are out of scope. But, according to VS-Code, they are still in **Running** mode.

[image]

I wait for them to `join()`. This mean that they are terminated. So, how they are still running? How to release those threads safely?

Comment: Couldn't replicate this situation outside of VSCode, my guess is that it's a problem in the editor, not in Python runtime. Your code actually cannot have 2 concurrent running threads, since you `join` the first thread before `start`ing second thread.

Comment: With which IDE you tested it? Someone can confirm that this is bug in VS-Code?

Comment: I ran it in terminal, with htop running in second terminal with filter on python turned on (you can turn it on with F4). As soon as threads joined, they disappeared from htop. I am on Linux.

Comment: Feel free to report a bug at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues

Comment: I just reported on this. URL = https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/1191

Answer (score 1):

- Go into ***launch.json*** (Ctrl+Shift+P and type the filename)
- Change the setting of your launch option from `"type":"python"` to `"type":"pythonExperimental"`

It seems to be a bug in vscode. The solution was post in response to the [issue that you reported.](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/1191)